# Copy Data using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have more than 100 tables in a database. I generate script and execute into another database. Now I want to insert data from source database into destination database (only data) daily basis.

So I can do comparison using SSIS. Can anyone have idea to copy data from source to destination on daily basis like jobs in SSIS ?

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find that we can use "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task" in SSIS. So it will help to copy selected object to another database.

Comment: Or you can drop and recreate the destination tables.  If there's too much data and you'd just like to copy over the new records every night (or more often), you can look into replication.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Copy Database Wizard

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

At the very end, check the create an SSIS package, schedule that SSIS package to run as often as you need, task complete.

Comment: Thanks but if I want to copy only few tables in a database what should I do ?

Comment: same concept, it lets you pick databases, stored procedures, tables, triggers, etc... you should play around with it if you're unfamiliar.